# Какое готовое решение можно использовать для регистрации-авторизиции пользователей на сайте?

Tags: php, безопасность, авторизация, регистрация

Во всех учебниках, статьях, мануалах говорится - не изобретайте велосипед, пользуйтесь готовыми решениями..

В этом и вопрос - какие существуют проверенные решения?

Сайт написан на PHP+MYSQL.

Нужен следующий функционал:
- регистрация;
- авторизация;
- восстановление пароля;
- (желательно) возможность создавать группы пользователей.

Хотелось бы с толковой документацией...

P.S. Сайт совсем небольшой.. Практически для себя и друзей.. Не вижу смысла тянуть для этого фреймворки

Comment: https://ruseller.com/project.php?id=5 http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/sistema-registracii-polzovateley-s-pomoschyu-php-i-mysql.html Посмотрите вот это...Мне кажется довольно интересные статьи... P.S. Если мой ответ помог, то отметьте его правильным)))Спасибо!

Comment: мне кажется, что это и есть самая сложная задача в вебе - управление пользователями и безопасность. Как раз лучше взять готовый фреймворк, если "сайт для друзей".

Comment: Обе ссылки как раз являются велосипедами, которые отвратительны с точки зрения безопасности и качества кода

Comment: _Готовые решения_ хорошо проработаны в фреймворках.

Comment: В таком случае качество безопасности очень хорошо проработаны во фреймворках... Там существуют хорошие готовые решения вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Библиотека с большими возможностями
https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth